# Auto-increment id field as primary key and version in Spring roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo

How do I create an auto-increment id field in Spring roo? I tried,

```
field number --fieldName id --type --notNull
```

What is it after this??

Also how do I create version for optimistic locking